# Ruby: ActiveRecord - index of Nth row

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I've got a database with an `id` index that occasionally has gaps.

How do you find the index of the Nth row using ActiveRecord?

Comment: Do you mean the `id` (key) of the n-th row (the term "index" is ambiguous)? And the result will depend upon how you have the list ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to still order them by `:id` (rather than, say `:created_at`), just grab the nth one from the database and look at its `id`.

```
Resource.order(:id).offset(n-1).limit(1).first.id
```

Answer (score 2):

This way gets the same answer as the previous answer, but works for arbitrarily large tables, since it only retrieves the one value from the database.

```
id = MyTable.order(:id).offset(n-1).limit(1).pluck(:id).first
```

Depends what you are trying to do ;)